# How to escape quotes properly?

Tags: r

I would like to generate the following result using R as string:

```
"hello"."myfriend"
```

After trying endless combinations with `paste` I come as close as:

```
 >'hello"."myfriend'
```

using `cat`

```
hi <- "'hello\".\"myfriend'"
cat(hi)
```

Idealy, I would like to pass that string including the quotes `"hello"."myfriend"` into a variable in order to pass it as an parameter somewhere else:

```
 hi <- "'hello\".\"myfriend'"
 par <–cat(hi)
 par

> "hello"."myfriend"
```

Comment: `cat('\"hello\".\"myfriend\"')` or `paste0(dQuote(c('hello', 'myfriend')), collapse = '.')` depending on what you want

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "generate"? You mean get that value to print to the console? Or to create a string which contains those exact characters (including the quotes?

Comment: @rawr @MrFlick Im using some amazon services where I have to pass the schema and a table as a string . I have decided to use R and struggle to pass `cat('\"hello\".\"myfriend\"')` as schema, where quotes must be inlcuded. Just realizing that cat is returning NULL which is not going to work out

Comment: cat() doesn’t return anything. It just prints the string without any escaping. If it looks right to you when you cat it out, the the string variable in R contains what you need. You should be able to “use” that string. I don’t know what you are doing with it afterwards, but it should be fine. The cat() is just useful for you to self check by bypassing the console’s usually string escaping rules.